# Insert user control in Material Design Dialog WPF

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to understand material design in xaml in WPF and at this moment I am working on Dialog Host. I tried to put UserControl in material design dialog host but somehow it is not working, I am using material design with Caliburn Micro FW.

MainView.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--ROW 0-->
    <Button Content="Show Dialog" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="OpenDialog"/>
    <!--ROW 1-->
    <materialDesign:DialogHost Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" IsOpen="{Binding IsDialogOpen}" CloseOnClickAway="True">
        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
            <StackPanel Margin="20">
                <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
    private bool _isDialogOpen;
    public bool IsDialogOpen
    {
        get { return _isDialogOpen; }
        set
        {
            _isDialogOpen = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsDialogOpen);
        }
    }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        MyCustomers.Add("Dhairya Joshi");
        MyCustomers.Add("Irfan Shethia");
        MyCustomers.Add("Imran Shethia");
    }

    public void OpenDialog()
    {
        IsDialogOpen = true;
        ActivateItem(new CustomersListViewModel());
    }
```

CustomerView.xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListBox x:Name="MyCustomers"/>
</StackPanel>
```

CustomerViewModel.cs

```
private List<string> _myCustomers = new List<string>();
    public List<string> MyCustomers
    {
        get { return _myCustomers; }
        set {
            _myCustomers = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyCustomers);
        }
    }

    public CustomersListViewModel()
    {
        MyCustomers.Add("Dhairya Joshi");
        MyCustomers.Add("Irfan Shethia");
        MyCustomers.Add("Imran Shethia");
    }
```

Right now it is just showing like this screen shot

[image].

NOTE : I tried to put the `<contentControl>` in new row and same code does works fine but it is just not showing when i am using it inside DialogHost. Tried to remove StackPanel also and left only with `<contentcontrol>` but still its not working.

Update:

Finally I was able to put it in working condition but again another problem arises is that ListBox which is inside User Control is not getting populated.

How I was able to show User Control in Dialog:

1) MainView.xaml

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" IsOpen="{Binding IsDialogOpen}" CloseOnClickAway="True" Identifier="RootDialog">
```

2) MainViewModel.cs

```
public async void OpenDialog()
    {
        //IsDialogOpen = true;


        var view = new CustomersListView
        {
            DataContext = new CustomerListViewModel();
        };

        //show the dialog
        var result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog", ExtendedOpenedEventHandler, ExtendedClosingEventHandler);
    }

    private void ExtendedOpenedEventHandler(object sender, DialogOpenedEventArgs eventargs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Detecting Opened Event");
    }
    private void ExtendedClosingEventHandler(object sender, DialogClosingEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

    }
```

If i run the usercontrol directly then listview populates but when i do it inside dialog it does not. Not sure why.

Answer (score -1):

it's work very good

https://github.com/bebenins/DialogRefreshIssue

good lock